# Access Values using Instance or Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a complex class and the code looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Address address; 
    public Address GetAddress { get; set; } //Property
    // Constructor 
    public Person() { address = new Address(); } 
}

public class Address
{ 
    // Properties 
    public String Street { get; set; } 
    public String City { get; set; } 
    // Constructor 
    public Address() { Street = "Madison"; City = "NY"; } 
}
```

My Action Methods(Trimmed Version) are as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    return View(person);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person person)
{
    ViewBag.City = person.address.City;
    return View();
}
```

From my View/.cshtml file: 
I can access values for address through Model's instance or the property.

1. When I bring up the View for the 1st time:
   If I access values through instance `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.address.Street)` --  I get the values set in the class constructor - Madison and NY. 
   If I access it through property - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetAddress.Street)`, I get blank values.
2. Inside my Controller Action method- `public ActionResult Index(Person person)`:
   If I access values using instance - `person.address.street/city`, I get the old values that were assigned to my model - Madison and NY.
   If I access values using property - `person.GetAddress.Street`, I get the updated values that were entered from View.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `address` is a field, not a property (it does not have `get; set;`) so the model binder cannot **set** the value, therefore you only set the values that were set in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

> If I access it through property - @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetAddress.Street), I get blank values

That's because you're never setting the `Person.GetAddress` *property* (an odd name for a property, sounds like it should be a method).  Therefore you're getting your blank value.

> If I access values using property - person.GetAddress.Street, I get the updated values that were entered from View

It sounds like you have the `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetAddress.Street)`, in which case you're populating that property value.  Then when you POST you are pulling the `person.GetAddress.Street` which includes the inputted data.

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason that `GetAddress` is giving you a blank text box is because it's not set. It looks like you might want that to be actually giving you the `Person`'s address, so you could change it like so:

   ```
   GetAddress
   {
       get { return address; } 
   }
   ```

Or alternatively, simply change the `address` field to a property:

```
public Address address { get; set; }
```

This gives you the ability to get rid of `GetAddress` altogether if you so choose.

2. If you were setting `GetAddress` with your text box, that would cause it to store the values that you pass in. Since, in your code sample, `GetAddress` is a standalone property that isn't actually attached to the `address` field of the `Person` class, then having a text box tied to it will only change the value of the `GetAddress` property rather than the actual `address` property as you expected. You might find that my alternative solution for question 1 would solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your property is not auto-linked to your field. `GetAddress { get; set; }` auto-generates a field, and the property acts as syntactic sugar for accessing those. If you just want to wrap `address` you could do the following:

```
public Address GetAddress
{
    get
    {
        return address;
    }
    set
    {
        address = value;
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can just get rid of your field, and do (which gives you public getters and setters):

```
public Address Address { get; set; }
```

Comment: You might want to change the case on the property `public Address Address {}` at the bottom of your post so that the property name case is different from the type. Something like: `public Address address { get; set; }`

Comment: General C# convention says that properties should be PascalCase. Exact usage/naming will of course depend on your work environment/team etc.

Comment: That's true, but I believe naming the property exactly the same as the type will mask the property and/or throw a compiler error.

Comment: The compiler can differentiate by usage, and while generally agree that this isn't the best practice, how you fix it largely depends on what you're working on and where.

Lower-casing a property goes against most companies/projects code guidelines, as well as the generally accepted conventions though, so I will avoid changing it in this example as what I have works fine.